# zxing library minimium SDK & core.jar

Tags: android, sdk, zxing

I'm trying to compile the ZxING BarCode scanner, that comes from default for SDK 7.  The problem here, is that I want to compile and test it on a SDK 4 device, so when I change in properties the android version and the target SDK on the ManifestFile a lot of errors appears. Is there a minimum SDK requirement for ZXING? Is there a version of the zxing library for older SDK's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "Is there a minimum SDK requirement for ZXING?"

Yes apparently so, SDK 7 =). Yet another reason to integrate with intents rather than including your own copy of the library.

The [All Downloads page on zxing site](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/downloads/list?can=1&q=&colspec=Filename%20Summary%20Uploaded%20ReleaseDate%20Size%20DownloadCount) contains links to old versions of the project zip. Perhaps one of the deprecated versions will work for you? (although at the cost of losing anything that got fixed with newer versions)

Comment: thanks for the link, I didn't find it on the zxing page. Also, as everybody says the intent is always the best option if the user have access to the android market.

Comment: Actually, there is no need for the market...Zxing makes the Barcode Scanner apk file available for direct download from their website. http://code.google.com/p/zxing/downloads/detail?name=BarcodeScanner4.0.apk

Comment: great idea!! that's better than being compiling zxing